# How to add counter columns in datatable ..?

Tags: javascript, datatables

i have a look example like this : https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html and how to add number or counter columns in this example ..?

im glad to everyone answer my question

Answer (score 2):

[Index column](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html)

> Highly-interactive tables often require a 'counter' column that contains the position for each row in the table. This column should not be sortable, and will change dynamically as the ordering and searching applied to the table is altered by the end user.

Add the property `order` on `DataTable` as [Index column](https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html):

```
 "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
```

Comment: yes i has look https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html , but my data came from ajax bdw .. like i say my code similar like this: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

Comment: @Ade, it does not matter where the data is coming from. It will add  a counter column that contains the position for each row in the table, simply adding the property will automatically do that for you..........

Comment: i see, i has test as like you assist, but the Name row value will be replace by counter columns

Comment: @Ade, no column should be replaced....probably you can update the question with some test data so that I can have a look........thanks.